# Do the number of the arguments converted from the stdin have to be the same as the number of placeholders in the command?

Tags: xargs

When `xargs` creates multiple arguments  from a stdin input stream (`-d` can specify the separator  for splitting a stdin input stream into several arguments), how does `xargs` rearrange them in the command it is to execute?

`xargs` has an option `-I` to specify the placeholders in the commands for where to replace with the arguments. When `xargs` creates multiple arguments  from a stdin input stream, does the placeholder have to occur the same number of times as the number of the arguments?

For example, do the number of the arguments converted from the stdin have to be the same as the number of placeholders in the command?

```
$ xargs -I x -d " " ls x x x
-l -t -r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this yourself

```
$ echo -n a b c d e f g | xargs -I x -d " " echo x x x
a a a
b b b
c c c
d d d
e e e
f f f
g g g
```

From the manual:

> -I replace-str
>     Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character.  **Implies -x and -L 1**.
>
> -L max-lines
>   Use at most max-lines nonblank input lines per command line.  Trailing blanks cause an input line to be logically continued on the next input line.  Implies -x.

So `-I` implies `-L 1` which means that only one argument is used for each invocation. As you can see, each occurrence of `x` is replaced with the argument.

There is also an effect that may be surprising at first:

```
$ echo a b c d e f g | xargs -I x -d " " echo x x x
a a a
b b b
c c c
d d d
e e e
f f f
g
 g
 g
```

Without option `-n`, echo will output a newline at the end. With option `-d`, `xargs` will not consider the newline to be a separator, instead it is part of the argument, hence the line breaks in the output for `g\n`: `g\n g\n g\n`.

Comment: Why are the last three `g\n`'s not in the same column?

Comment: I thought I already explained that, but I made it more explicit now.